# How can I check URLs SSL is Lets encrypt Programmatically?

Tags: python, ruby, ssl, lets-encrypt

I need to find if a domain list was issued with lets encrypt. As it is a very long list I would like to do with programming. I researched how to do it with ruby ​​​​ and python but I didn't find many possibilities.

I found was the following code:

```
uri = URI::HTTPS.build(host: domain_name)
response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port, :use_ssl => true)
cert = response.peer_cert
```

This gives you an object of certificate in the cert variable. This variable is of the type OpenSSL::X509::Certificate. These are called X.509 certificates, and they are the standard for public key certificates.

But I can't find the certifying organization to know if it was Lets encrypt.

Comment: Have you checked `cert.issuer` ? This should be the name for an intermediate CA from Let's Encrypt, see https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/. If course somebody else could name its own CA certificate exactly the same, so if you need to be really sure you need to check the trust chain.

Comment: You could also set `ca_file` to a file only containing the Let's Encrypt root CA and intermediate CA. Validation will then simply fail if the certificate was not issued by Let's Encrypt.

Comment: 2 ways: 1) verify the cert against the Lets Encrypt CA cert. 2) open the ssl context and get the name of the CA.